# Fill in missing data based on dates and previous values

Tags: python, pandas

Thanks in advance for your help!

Here's a simple dataframe of the riddle I'm trying to solve:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {"Company ID": ["111", "111", "111", "111", "111", "111",],
        "Company Name": ["xyz", "xyz", "xyz", "xyz", "xyz", "xyz",],
        "Month": ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",],
        "Value": [100, 100, 0, 0, 0, 100,],
       }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df
```

Is there a way I can change the 0 values to 100 **IF** the company ID goes from a positive value to 0 and then back to a positive value **within ~6 months**? I know this df doesn't support a time lookup, but I should be able to figure that out if I can solve for the missing data.

Note: My dataset has thousands of rows and I'll be wanting to solve values based on the unique company IDs.

The final result for this example should show a value of 100 in each month, however, the value *and* missing months will be different depending on the company.

@jl31, If you want to use this data, please use:

```
data = {"Company ID": ["111", "222", "333", "444", "555", "111","666", "222", "444", "333", "555", "666"],
        "Company Name": ["abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno", "aaa","pqr", "def", "jkl", "ghi", "mno", "pqr"],
        "Month": pd.date_range(start="2020-01-01",end="2020-12-01",freq='MS'),
        "Value": [100, 100, 100, 100, 0, 0, 0, 100, 0, 0, 0, 100],
       }
```

This will be setup as:

```
   Company ID Company Name      Month  Value
0         111          abc 2020-01-01    100
5         111          aaa 2020-06-01      0
1         222          def 2020-02-01    100
7         222          def 2020-08-01    100
2         333          ghi 2020-03-01    100
9         333          ghi 2020-10-01      0
3         444          jkl 2020-04-01    100
8         444          jkl 2020-09-01      0
4         555          mno 2020-05-01      0
10        555          mno 2020-11-01      0
6         666          pqr 2020-07-01      0
11        666          pqr 2020-12-01    100
```

Comment: if a month name is repeated, how will you know if it is from the following year or same year? I think, it will be worthwhile if you can provide a more realistic data, where company ids are unique, months problem is addressed, and if any other column/condition is also available!

Comment: @anurag in the real dataset I am using real dates, but for this example I just put something together quickly. The harder question I'm trying to solve is how to fill the gaps between the redundant data.

Comment: we can think up a logic better if you can provide sample realistic data, else errors may creep in

Comment: In your example you have 1 company ID. Make a better example please.

Comment: I have been trying to solve this for a while. Do you want to use this data...  data = {"Company ID": ["111", "222", "333", "444", "555", "111","666", "222", "444", "333", "555", "666"],
        "Company Name": ["abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno", "aaa","pqr", "def", "jkl", "ghi", "mno", "pqr"],
        "Month": pd.date_range(start="2020-01-01",end="2020-12-01",freq='MS'),
        "Value": [100, 100, 100, 100, 0, 0, 0, 100, 0, 0, 0, 100],
       }

Comment: @jl31, I assume you want ID=111 to have 100, 333 not to have 100, 444 to have 100, and 666 to have 100. Let me know if that's what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried various methods to address this but the only solution that I could find is to iterate through the rows. I will try and find a better solution.

For now, here's how we can get the outcome.

- Step 1: Iterate through each row in the dataframe
- Step 2: For each row, match by Company ID, then check if Month is
  within range. To check for range: check for last 6 months and next 6
  month from current month (row.Month). Any of these ranges would meet
  the 6 month criteria
- Step 3: Find the Min and Max value from the `Value` column. This will
  result in (0 and a positive value with max as 100) or (0 and 0). If
  Min = 0 & Max != 0, then the value dipped to 0 and returned to a
  positive value so we can set newVal to 100.

The code for this is:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {"Company ID": ["111", "222", "333", "444", "555", "111","666", "222", "444", "333", "555", "666"],
        "Company Name": ["abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno", "aaa","pqr", "def", "jkl", "ghi", "mno", "pqr"],
        "Month": pd.date_range(start="2020-01-01",end="2020-12-01",freq='MS'),
        "Value": [100, 100, 100, 100, 0, 0, 0, 100, 0, 0, 0, 100],
       }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.sort_values(by=['Company ID'], inplace=True)
print (df)

for idx, row in df.iterrows():

    df.loc[idx,'maxVal'] = (df[(row['Company ID']==df['Company ID']) & (df['Month'] <= row.Month + pd.tseries.offsets.MonthBegin(6)) & (df['Month'] >= row.Month - pd.tseries.offsets.MonthBegin(6))]['Value'].max())
    df.loc[idx,'minVal'] = (df[(row['Company ID']==df['Company ID']) & (df['Month'] <= row.Month + pd.tseries.offsets.MonthBegin(6)) & (df['Month'] >= row.Month - pd.tseries.offsets.MonthBegin(6))]['Value'].min())
    
    if df.loc[idx,'minVal'] == 0 and df.loc[idx,'maxVal'] != 0:
        df.loc[idx,'newVal'] = 100
    else:
        df.loc[idx,'newVal'] = 0

df.sort_values(by=['Company ID'], inplace=True)
print (df)
```

The output of this will be:

Input DataFrame:

```
   Company ID Company Name      Month  Value
0         111          abc 2020-01-01    100
5         111          aaa 2020-06-01      0   #should change to 100; range within 6 months
1         222          def 2020-02-01    100
7         222          def 2020-08-01    100
2         333          ghi 2020-03-01    100
9         333          ghi 2020-10-01      0   #should NOT change to 100, range outside 6 months
3         444          jkl 2020-04-01    100
8         444          jkl 2020-09-01      0   #should change to 100, range within 6 months
4         555          mno 2020-05-01      0
10        555          mno 2020-11-01      0
6         666          pqr 2020-07-01      0   #should change to 100, range within 6 months
11        666          pqr 2020-12-01    100
```

Updated DataFrame:

```
   Company ID Company Name      Month  Value  maxVal  minVal  newVal
0         111          abc 2020-01-01    100   100.0     0.0   100.0
5         111          aaa 2020-06-01      0   100.0     0.0   100.0
1         222          def 2020-02-01    100   100.0   100.0     0.0
7         222          def 2020-08-01    100   100.0   100.0     0.0
2         333          ghi 2020-03-01    100   100.0   100.0     0.0
9         333          ghi 2020-10-01      0     0.0     0.0     0.0
3         444          jkl 2020-04-01    100   100.0     0.0   100.0
8         444          jkl 2020-09-01      0   100.0     0.0   100.0
4         555          mno 2020-05-01      0     0.0     0.0     0.0
10        555          mno 2020-11-01      0     0.0     0.0     0.0
6         666          pqr 2020-07-01      0   100.0     0.0   100.0
11        666          pqr 2020-12-01    100   100.0     0.0   100.0
```

After dropping the minVal & maxVal columns, you will have:

```
   Company ID Company Name      Month  Value  newVal
0         111          abc 2020-01-01    100   100.0
5         111          aaa 2020-06-01      0   100.0  #Updated as expected
1         222          def 2020-02-01    100     0.0
7         222          def 2020-08-01    100     0.0
2         333          ghi 2020-03-01    100     0.0
9         333          ghi 2020-10-01      0     0.0  #Did NOT Update as expected
3         444          jkl 2020-04-01    100   100.0
8         444          jkl 2020-09-01      0   100.0  #Updated as expected
4         555          mno 2020-05-01      0     0.0
10        555          mno 2020-11-01      0     0.0
6         666          pqr 2020-07-01      0   100.0  #Updated as expected
11        666          pqr 2020-12-01    100   100.0
```

Comment: If this solved your question, please consider accepting the answer by clicking on the green check box